# Why is including an obj model in my XR viewer scene breaking it?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, webvr

Using the Anchor tag examples from https://examples.webxrexperiments.com/examples/ar_anchors/

I'm trying to include A-Frame and obj models instead of three.js geometric objects, but I'm facing many issues.

My three questions are 
First, what would cause the camera to be inside of the model?
Second, why doesn't scale and position do anything to the model?
Third, why does x, y, z-axis movement not work properly?

Here's the glitch page https://glitch.com/edit/#!/faithful-hyena

Note: You need to install the XR viewer on an AR-capable device to run the site.